# I am getting null values from registration panel to my database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying save data about registred users/client to database but I am getting null values. I have been looking what causes this but I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have posted four of my classes.

In IntelljIDEA i have such Hibernate query

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('client_sequence')
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        client
        (email, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, age, appUserRole, gender, loginName, password, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

RegistrationController

```
    package com.example.demo.registration;

    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/registration")
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class RegistrationController {

     RegistrationService registrationService;



     /* HTTP GET Request for read registartion.html page from server */
     @GetMapping
     public String showRegistrationPanel() {
         return "registration";
     }

     /* HTTP POST Request for insert data to database on server */
     @PostMapping
     public String register(@ModelAttribute("client") RegistrationDTO request, Model model) {
             registrationService.register(request);
             model.addAttribute("client",request);
           return "redirect:/registration?success";
     }

    }
```

RegistrationService

```
    package com.example.demo.registration;

    import com.example.demo.client.AppUserRole;
    import com.example.demo.client.Client;
    import com.example.demo.client.ClientService;
    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    @Service
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class RegistrationService {

    /*   */
    private final ClientService clientService;
    /*  */
    private final EmailValidator emailValidator;

    /* Method register new user to system  */
    public Client register(RegistrationDTO request) {
        /* Check if Email is valid */
      /*  boolean isValidEmail = emailValidator.test(request.getEmail());
        if(!isValidEmail) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("email not valid");
        } */
        /* This method uses clientService to register new client */
        return clientService.signUpClient(
            new Client(
                    request.getFirstName(),
                    request.getLastName(),
                    request.getEmail(),
                    request.getPhoneNumber(),
                    request.getLoginName(),
                    request.getPassword(),
                    AppUserRole.USER
            )
        );

    }
}
```

ClientService

```
package com.example.demo.client;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service("clientService")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ClientService implements UserDetailsService {


    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND = "user with email %s not found";
    private final ClientRepository clientRepository;

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return clientRepository.findAll();
    }


    public void saveClient(Client client) {
        clientRepository.save(client);
    }

    public void deleteClient(Client client) {
        clientRepository.delete(client);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return clientRepository.findByEmail(username).
                orElseThrow(() ->
                        new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND)));
    }

    
    public Client signUpClient(Client client) {
      
        //    String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(client.getPassword());

        //  client.setPassword(encodedPassword);

       return clientRepository.save(client);

    }

 }

}
```

Client

```
package com.example.demo.client;

import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

@Entity
@Table(name="client",uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="Id",column=@Column(name="Id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="firstName",column=@Column(name="firstName")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="lastName",column=@Column(name="lastName")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="email",column=@Column(name="email")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="phoneNumber",column=@Column(name="phoneNumber"))
})
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Client extends Person implements UserDetails {


    @Column(name="age")
    private int age;
    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;
    @Column(name="loginName")
    private String loginName;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Enumerated (EnumType.STRING)
    private AppUserRole appUserRole;
  

    public Client(String firstName, String lastName, String email,
                  String phoneNumber, String loginName,String password,AppUserRole appUserRole) {
        super(firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber);
        this.loginName = loginName;
        this.password = password;
        this.appUserRole = appUserRole;
    }

    public Client(String firstName, String lastName, String email,
                  String phoneNumber, int age, String gender,
                  String loginName,String password,AppUserRole appUserRole) {
        super(firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber);
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.loginName = loginName;
        this.password = password;
        this.appUserRole = appUserRole;
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority =
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority(appUserRole.name());
        return Collections.singletonList(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return loginName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the code to github and then a link here, otherwise its hard to debug

Comment: Ok but it take my some time because I have never used github before.

Comment: It will be good experience ! :)

Comment: @ArthurKlezovich I posted my project on Github : https://github.com/PLGP2020/ManagementSystem/tree/master